# Mongo request slow

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying Mongo with a million enties. My request is really slow.

Do you have any ideas to optimize it ?

```
db.financial_transaction.runCommand({ 
    "aggregate": "financial_transaction", 
    "pipeline": [ { 
        "$match": { 
            "transaction_type": { "$in": [ 1, 2 ] }, 
            "created_at": { "$gte": new ISODate("2016-03-13T00:00:00+01:00"), "$lte": new ISODate("2017-12-13T23:59:00+01:00") }, 
            "type": { "$in": [ "A", "C", "E" ] }, 
            "sid": { "$in": [ 1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13 ] }, 
            "context": { "$in": [ "CL", "RE" ] } } 
        }, { 
       "$group": { "_id": { "paymentType": "$payment_type", 
                            "paymentMethod": "$payment_method", 
                            "responseCode": "$response_code", 
                            "reasonCode": "$reason_code" 
         }, 
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }, "total_amount": { "$sum": "$requested_amount" } } }, { "$sort": { "count": -1 } } ] 
});
```

Indexes:

```
_id_
idx_context
idx_payment_method
idx_response_code
idx_reason_code
idx_created_at
idx_transaction_type
idc_payment_method_created_at_transaction_type_origin_auth_system
idx_created_at_context_transaction_type
idx_updated_at
```

I made a gist with the explain result: https://gist.github.com/sanchobouillant/bd59403242ebb1ec45582dff74b457a2

Comment: Can you do an explain on the query? Just so we can see what it's using (I'm guessing it's idx_created_at_context_transaction_type)

Comment: Can you explain how to do an explain on the query with the runCommand ?

Comment: Not sure, can't you just use the normal `aggregate` method?

Comment: I made a gist with the explain command https://gist.github.com/sanchobouillant/bd59403242ebb1ec45582dff74b457a2

Comment: One last thing. Can you also run `db.financial_transaction.stats()` and paste it in the ticket as well?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sanchobouillant/6cd9db7495cecb03921013d0b674e539 :)